# Syntax in Haskell/Elm

Tags: haskell, elm

Can't find anything about this syntax in Haskel/Elm:

```
bar day yOffset =
    rect
        [
            x <| toString <| (day.xOffset * (barWidth + barMargin)),
            y <| toString <| if day.amount <= 0 then yOffset
                else yOffset - day.amount,
            height <| toString <| abs day.amount,
            width <| toString barWidth
        ]
        [ Svg.title [] [ text day.day ] ]

min = List.map (\x -> x.words) lastTwoWeeks
            |> List.minimum
            |> Maybe.withDefault 0
            |> (\x -> if x > 0 then 0 else x)
```

What does mean <| and |> ?

Comment: @Squidly you confused the order of the operands or the operator...

Comment: I've heard these infix operators lovingly referred to as left pizza and right pizza operators. Prior to that in F# the typical phrasing I see is pipe forward and pipe backward operators.

Answer (score 9):

It isn't syntax, it's just a normal Elm function. From [http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Basics#%3C|](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Basics#%3C%7C):

> `(<|) : (a -> b) -> a -> b`
>
> Backward function application `f <| x == f x`. This function is useful for avoiding parenthesis

and similarly `x |> f == f x`. The Haskell equivalent of `<|` is called `$`, and `|>` is `Data.Function.&` (added in Base 4.8.0.0).